# Start playlist via cli on vlc --one-instance

Tags: bash, arguments, command-line-interface, vlc

I ran `vlc --one-instance` in a terminal. vlc starts as expected with an empty playlist.

Then I ran `vlc --one-instance --playlist-enqueue audio.mp3` in a second terminal. As expected, the audio file was added to the vlc playlist.

But now I don't know how to start playing the songs in the playlist of that active instance from the cli. I check `vlc --longhelp --advanced` for possible options, but I couldn't find any way to issue commands to my running instance.

Comment: what's the way you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried because I haven't found a `play` command to execute via cli